# curl não faz requisição

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou criando um *script* que faz *login* em uma página e me retorna o HTMLda página `/logado`, mas não está funcionando e pelo que vi o código está correto

Onde errei?

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST["bin"])){
$bin = $_POST["bin"];
$email = explode("|", $bin)[0];
$senha = explode("|", $bin)[1];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://minhaconta.payleven.com.br/login_check");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '_username=' . urlencode($email) . '&_password=' . urlencode($senha));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$dados = curl_exec($ch);

echo "$dados";

}else{ echo 'erro'; }
?>
```

Comment: O que aparece na página? Qual é o valor final de `$dados`?

Comment: Eu desejo que ele em seguida vá para https://minhaconta.payleven.com.br/dashboard e me retorne oque estiver la

Comment: Isso não respondeu a pergunta anterior. O que aparece na tela e qual é o valor em `$dados`? Pode usar a função [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.var-dump.php).

Comment: Não sei se é isso, mas se você usar o `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` até onde eu saiba ele inicia uma nova sessão, descartando os dados da sessão que estão em `'cookie.txt'` (cookies que não tem data para expirar = sessão). Ou seja, ele vai seguir o `location` e não vai usar os cookies de sessão. Não sei se é isso, não estou confiante que seja isso, mas experimente remover essa linha. :)

Comment: Anderson em dados estaria o html de minha requisição

Comment: Veja nos cabeçalhos qual é o caminho que faz. Se ele chega a entrar na próxima página e volta para a página de login ou se ele nunca entrou.

Comment: Remover o cookiesession resolveu o problema obrigado amigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se usa o `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` você força o cURL ignorar os cookies de sessão, considere "cookies de sessão" como os cookies que não possuem data para expirar.

---

Quando envia a requisição para `/login_check` ele armazena os cookies em `cookie.txt` (definido em `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`). Quando a combinação de login/senha for válida irá redirecionar para outra página, esta página será seguida devido ao `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` e irá usar os cookies previamente salvos devido ao `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`.

Porém, com a combinação do `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` essa nova requisição não irá conter os cookies de sessão.

---

Remova o `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);` ou defina para `false`, que é o padrão.

Comment: poderia me ajudar? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/219104/bad-authentication-data-curl-twitter-api

Comment: ví umas respostas sua e vi uma que vc fala de basic authentication. na minha pergunta acho que preciso disto.